# Calculate Audio Buffer size in AudioQueue in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to record audio from microphone form 1(min) sec to 15 sec(max). Recording time may be vary between 1 to 15 sec. So how i can calculate size of buffer or resize buffer size. My `AudioStreamBasicDescription` setting is-

```
this.audioStreamDescription.Format = AudioFormatType.LinearPCM;
this.audioStreamDescription.FormatFlags = AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsSignedInteger | AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsPacked;                                                   
this.audioStreamDescription.SampleRate = 8000;
this.audioStreamDescription.BitsPerChannel = 16;
this.audioStreamDescription.ChannelsPerFrame = 1;
this.audioStreamDescription.BytesPerFrame = (16 / 8) * 1;
this.audioStreamDescription.FramesPerPacket = 1;
this.audioStreamDescription.BytesPerPacket = audioStreamDescription.BytesPerFrame * audioStreamDescription.FramesPerPacket;
this.audioStreamDescription.Reserved = 0;
```

Alocating buffer -

```
inputQueue.AllocateBuffer(-----, out bufferPointer);
inputQueue.EnqueueBuffer(bufferPointer, -----, null);
```